# One of the two setContentView() not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is the code I have written. I have implemented `LocationListener` methods which I did not paste here. I felt it is unnecessary.
Here I want the `activity_main.xml` to be displayed for the first launch. So I used `SharedPreferences` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703065/showing-the-setup-screen-only-on-first-launch-in-android). Even when the app is launched for the first time, the `activity_main.xml` is not showing up. The `Toast` notification saying Registration started is displayed so I know the `if` statement is getting executed. I can't figure out why `activity_map` is always loading.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
EditText d_name,d_phone,d_email;
Button submit=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("hello", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(pref.getBoolean("firststart", true)){
        //Checking weather this is executed or not
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration started", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //setting layout on the screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // update sharedpreference - another start wont be the first
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firststart", false);
        editor.commit(); // apply changes
        // first start, show your dialog | first-run code goes here
        d_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_name);
        d_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.d_phone);
        d_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.d_mail);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = d_name.getText().toString();
                final long ph =Long.parseLong(d_phone.getText().toString());
                final String mail = d_email.getText().toString();   
                '
                '
                .(Save to db)
            }});
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    initializeMap();
}
```

If needed, this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/details"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/d_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    android:layout_below="@id/details"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/d_phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/d_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_phone"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/d_mail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/d_phone"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/d_mail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/button" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prasad.currentlocator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBLG6F6G8Yi9MYDPdyetgSVgXxhVNYIdyw" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
```

is always getting called because it runs after everythin g in `if`. You need an `if/else`

```
if(pref.getBoolean("firststart", true)){
    // do all your stuff
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // do anything else that should run if not first start
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. You are correct. It worked.And thanks for the edits. It's so kind.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting wrong `setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);` . Little mistake in your statement .

1. **Where is your** `else {}` **Part**

At first Set `if-else` block properly .

Comment: @Krishna No problem .Move ahead

Comment: He's first sir. Just want to ask SO to give us the chance to mark multiple answers correct. National feeling is difficult to overcome. Because of you I got the feeling that I'm not lonely in programming field.

Comment: @Krishna Iknow .You did perfect . I am here for `"Getting Knowledge"` . Not `Reputations`

Comment: Ya, I know you did that. :-)

Comment: @Krishna something like that, you would need to ask on [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest). Though, I just checked and [it was asked recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267545/allow-accepting-multiple-answers). Not much of a discussion on that post

Comment: BTW. I want the acticvity_map to load always. For example, if the it is the first launch, It should show registration window first and after registration, main layout should be up. If it is not the first launch, then only the second layout should come up directly. So in that case, I cannot use `else` right? Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Okay you can use `Set visibility GONE`

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView()` is called twice in your code. Make sure that in your onCreate() the `setContentView()` is encountered only once in all flows. Here you need to have an `else` statement.

From my experience, I would suggest that you call setContentView() outside the If/Else, i.e, have just one layout. Then, based on the condition alter the stuff inside the layout. I suggest this, because this would later become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Henry. I'll do it.