# Android language buttons activity runs on first time and keep the selection

Tags: android, multilingual

I am new on programming and make something like this for the first time. I found some examples, but nothing like this.

I am trying to create an activity with just two buttons with flags, that appears when the app installed and run for the first time.
The user, choose his language and then the app has to keep the selection and open it every time with that selection, without run again that activity. I have already translate and make a string-fr and change also some drawables.
The problem is, that I have one Splash activity on the begining (which run every time), then the Language selection activity and after that a WelcomeActivity - which also appears only the first time the app runs.
First of all, my Language activity appears every time the app runs and doesn't keep the selection.
Also, I am trying, when the Language activity runs, somehow not set firstrun as false in order WelcomeActivity runs.
This is language.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/fr"
    android:background="@drawable/flag_fr"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/en"
    android:background="@drawable/flag_en"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Language.java

```
public class Language extends Activity{

SharedPreferences sharedPref = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Button fr,en;
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.language);

    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    fr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fr);
    en = (Button) findViewById(R.id.en);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {

        fr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLocale("fr");
            }
        });
        en.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLocale("en");
            }
        });
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

and this is my Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="MainActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".Language"
        android:label="Language"/>
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am sure that is something easy, but I cannot find it..Thank you!

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703065/showing-the-setup-screen-only-on-first-launch-in-android

Comment: Please read my question..As you can see from my code, I know how to run an activity when the app starts for the first time.. My problem is that it doesn't work the language options.. Thank you.